# Need help understanding syntax/logic in Ruby bubble sort solution

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, bubble-sort

I need help understanding some of the syntax and logic in this programming solution.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

Specifically, I had some trouble understanding the part with the `until` loop and the `sorted = true` and `sorted = false`. I did some reading on here and I think I get that if changes need to be made to the array still, `sorted` gets set to `false` and the loop continues. But I'd be appreciated if someone could explain this to me simply one more time.

It looks like the times loop only executes once for each array element minus one and then swaps the positions. How does the until loop play into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.times` loop does a single pass over the array, comparing each element with its neighbor and swapping them if they're in the wrong order.

The outer `until sorted` loop repeats this process until nothing changes anymore. At this point the array is sorted.

The `sorted` variable records whether we swapped any elements during our last pass over the array. If we did, the array changed and we're not done yet. On the other hand, if no elements were swapped, `sorted = false` is not executed, `sorted` remains `true`, and we can exit the outer loop.

Comment: Thank you, you were very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that it iterates through the array, checking values and swapping if needed - if a swap has been made at all in that process it considers the array to be unsorted and sets sorted = false. If that is the case, the until loop will ensure an *entire new pass* happens across the array, to redo the process again. The only time the until loop stops is when there was not a single swap done during a pass. At the beginning of each until loop sorted is set to true because it assumes this will be the last pass - unless a swap is made which sets sorted = false, then it will be doing at least one more pass.

Check out http://visualgo.net/sorting.html# if you'd like a neat animation to visualize what's happening in various sorting algorithms.

Comment: The animation is great!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it was very helpful! The animation was great too!